# weird CSS bug in my woocommerce site

Tags: css, woocommerce

I got a weird bug that weridly I can't mange to fix, look at this page:
http://portofinocoffe.wpengine.com/cart/

You can see a green button with a "bump" on it's top.
I can remove it only if I put `padding: 0` to the button, but what if I want padding top?
Why this is happening?

Thank you!

EDIT:
OK I see there's a `<br>` there that cause the problem, but I can't find it in the code. Here's the code generates the button:

```
<p class="return-to-shop">
    <a class="button wc-backward" href="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) ) ); ?>">
        <?php _e( 'Return To Shop', 'woocommerce' ) ?>
    </a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this button?

[image: Button]

```
<a class="button wc-backward" href="http://portofinocoffe.wpengine.com/%d7%97%d7%a0%d7%95%d7%aa/"><br>
        חזור לחנות  </a>
```

There's a `<br>` at the end that moves it to the next line. Remove it and you're done.

Comment: I see, but there's something weird there. I edited my post

Comment: Try putting the code that generates the button on one single line. Like this: `<a class="button wc-backward" href="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Return To Shop', 'woocommerce' ) ?></a>`

Comment: Thanks that worked! But what is that strange behavior, it's the first time I see that a tag is added automatically. Why is that? the fact the I descending line on the editor doesn't suppose to affect the html.

Comment: I don't really have a clue, but sometimes the PHP will render differently if not single lined.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the height of the button, use something like this:

```
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 16px;
```

Without padding-top and padding-bottom.

Peter